# remove before specific string not character

Tags: php, substr, strstr

Format of `string` is as follow

```
$img = "/images/posts/main.jpg";
$img1 = "/images/posts/john.jpg";
```

I need to remove `/images/posts/` and echo rest of the content.

I tried with `strstr`, But I found it deals with only character

```
echo strstr($img, '/images/posts/')
//output => /images/posts/main.jpg
```

if I use only single character `echo strstr($img, '/')` Then output is `images/posts/`.

So I use `substr` with `strstr` to get expected result.

```
echo substr(strstr($img, '/'), 14);
//output => main.jpg
```

In my case, I am sure it will work constantly with same result because the part `images/posts/` remains same and will not change.

But is it really good or fast way to counting and trimming ? Any other fast way to cut `/images/posts/` at once ?

**Or replace ? is it faster ??**

```
echo str_replace('/images/posts/','',$img);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this..

Syntax-

```
 str_replace(find, replace, string, count)
```

For Eg-

```
str_replace('/images/posts/', '', '/images/posts/main.jpg');
```

it will print main.jpg

Comment: is `replace` faster ?